# How can i handle connection and reconnect if connection got closed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, spring-webclient

I need this client stay connected for long, How can i make sure about connection? because the issue was in connection, so i am updating my question. what should i do if server close connection? or if client close connection? how can i handle it and reconnect client to the server?

```
public void consumeServerSentEvent() {
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/sse-server");
ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
 = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};

Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
  .uri("/stream-sse")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(type);

eventStream.subscribe(
  content -> logger.info("Time: {} - event: name[{}], id [{}], content[{}] ",
    LocalTime.now(), content.event(), content.id(), content.data()),
  error -> logger.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error),
  () -> logger.info("Completed!!!"));
```

}

Comment: Fariba, Did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [retrieve()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#retrieve--) returns *Mono* of [ClientResponse](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html), but for your case you need to consume *Flux* of the body.
Try some thing like this:

```
Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
   .uri("/stream-sse")
   .retrieve()
   .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(type));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my issue was in connection, server was closing the connection, i updated my question about how can i handle connection and reconnect client to server if connection became close by client or server?